# Problem with Observer Pattern and bar chart using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, observer-pattern

I've got a problem, I'd like to have a bar chart with series automatically update with Observer Pattern. The problem is: when the update function is called nothing append on the chart. Here is the code I use : 
The first class is the class which provides me my data.

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class ChartModel extends Observable {
    private  String[] dataName;
    private static double[] data;

    public ChartModel(){
        dataName=new String[4];
        data=new double[4];
    }

    public String[] getDataName(){
        return dataName;
    } 

    public double[] getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setChartData(String[] d, double[] dd){
        for(int i=0; i<dataName.length; i++){
            dataName[i]=d[i];
            data[i]=dd[i];
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void updateCharData(String dataName, double newData){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<dataName.length() && !this.dataName[i].equals(dataName); i++);
        if(i<dataName.length())
            data[i]=newData;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Now here is my chart class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class MyBarChart extends Application implements Observer {

private String[] dataName;
private double[] data;
BarChart<String, Number> bc;

public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Graphique");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    bc=new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Etudiants");
    xAxis.setLabel("Sections");
    //xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
    yAxis.setLabel("Nombre d'élèves");

    Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if(o instanceof ChartModel){
        ChartModel cm=(ChartModel) o;
        dataName=cm.getDataName();
        data=cm.getData();
        for(int i=0; i<dataName.length; i++){
            System.out.println(dataName[i]+ " " +data[i]);
        }
        bc.getData().clear();
        for(int i=0; i<dataName.length; i++){
            XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
            series1.setName(dataName[i]);
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(data[i], dataName[i]));
            bc.getData().addAll(series1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] dataName=new String[]{"Informatique","Infirmier","Kine", "Compta"};
    double[] data=new double[]{10,20,30,40};
    ChartModel cm=new ChartModel();
    launch(args);
    cm.setChartData(dataName, data);
    MyBarChart bc=new MyBarChart();
    cm.addObserver(bc);
    //cm.updateCharData("Informatique", 50);
/*        try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){//trt
        }
        cm.updateCharData("Informatique", 10);
    try{ Thread.sleep(5000); }
    catch (InterruptedException e){//trt
         }*/
  }
}
```

Do you know what can I do to solve that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (simplified) lifecycle of a JavaFX application is as follows:

1. `Application.launch` is called and this launches the toolkit ect.

   1. An instance of the `Application` class that is used is created.
   2. Repeated event handling/rendering/layout ect.
2. When JavaFX determines it should shut down, it does some cleanup and `Application.launch` returns.

For this reason the code in the main method after

```
launch(args);
```

is executed after the GUI is closed.
Furthermore since `Application.launch` creates it's own instance of the application class there won't be any updates to the GUI. (You're adding a different instance as observer).

Also note that your application freezes as long as a longrunning operation on the JavaFX application thread is running. For this reason you need to make sure the updates to the model are done on a seperate thread. This also requires you to ensure updates to the GUI are done on the JavaFX application thread (For performance reason JavaFX assumes accesses to the GUI are only done from this thread.).

---

Some parts of your `ChartModel` class seem odd:

- `data` is `static` but `dataName` is not
- You seem to reinvent the wheel: You could simply use a `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>` instead of using 2 arrays to store the data
- access to the data is not synchronized leading to potential concurrency issues
- `Observable` was deprecated in Java 9
- In `updateCharData` the length of the string parameter is used in the loop condition and the `if` condition

The following code demonstrates starting the updates from the `start` method and doing the updates from a seperate thread. It also changes the way the data is stored to a `LinkedHashMap` to avoid implementing map-like functionality.

```
public class MyBarChart extends Application implements Observer {
    BarChart<String, Number> bc;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Graphique");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        bc = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Etudiants");
        xAxis.setLabel("Sections");
        //xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Nombre d'élèves");

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        initModel();
    }

    private void initModel() {
        String[] dataName = new String[]{"Informatique", "Infirmier", "Kine", "Compta"};
        double[] data = new double[]{10, 20, 30, 40};
        ChartModel cm = new ChartModel();
        cm.setChartData(dataName, data);
        cm.addObserver(this);
        new Thread(() -> {
            cm.updateCharData("Informatique", 50);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {//trt
            }
            cm.updateCharData("Informatique", 10);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {//trt
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (o instanceof ChartModel) {
            ChartModel cm = (ChartModel) o;
            Map<String, Double> data = cm.getData();

            // make sure to read the data from the thread that does the updates
            // or make sure the data is synchronized

            final XYChart.Series<String, Number>[] series = new XYChart.Series[data.size()];

            int index = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : cm.getData().entrySet()) {
                XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
                series1.setName(entry.getKey());
                series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                series[index] = series1;
                index++;
            }

            // updates to the gui on the javafx application thread
            Platform.runLater(() -> bc.getData().setAll(series));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class ChartModel extends Observable {

    private final Map<String, Double> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Double> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setChartData(String[] d, double[] dd) {
        if (d.length != dd.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            data.put(d[i], dd[i]);
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void updateCharData(String dataName, double newData) {
        data.put(dataName, newData);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and the explaination of the JavaFX application lifecycle.
For the odd parts : 
   - Static : I made a mistake I don't know why I put that I was probably tired haha.
   - For hashmap : I thought to use one but to test my application first I used two array and wanted to upgrade to hashmap after.
   - You're right for the data access I didn't thought about that (shame on me)
   - I know that oberserver/observable are depreciated but it's a school exercice and the professor want us to use that.

Once again, thank you very much for your answer!